# Flutter + Firebase Authentication - update user after updateProfile

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to update user profile and then reloading it and getting back updated user.

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
updateDisplayName(user, displayname) async {
  await user.updateProfile(displayName: displayname);
  await user.reload().then((user) {
    return auth.currentUser;
  });
}
```

And then I am calling the above 'updateDisplayName' in an InkWell

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    user = updateDisplayName(widget.username, displayName);
    print(user);
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) =>
              MobileNumberScreen(widget.username),
        ));
  },
  child: ....
)
```

The print in onTap returns

> flutter: Instance of 'Future'

Basically what I want is I want to update the display name and return updated user so going forward from here I have the user with updated details.

Answer (score 0):

The print returns `flutter: Instance of 'Future'`, because your `updateDisplayName(...)` method has a Future return type (the equivalent of void for an async). It does not return anything, it just waits until the async calls inside are done.

`return auth.currentUser;` is NOT returning your user object from `updateDisplayName(...)`, it is returning your user object from within the callback method inside `then(...)`.

Try this:

```
Future<User> updateDisplayName(user, displayname) async {
  await user.updateProfile(displayName: displayname);
  await user.reload(); //reload() is of type Future<void>, so it makes no sense to call .then() on it
  return user; //or return auth.currentUser, it should be the same
}
```

Also, it makes no sense to use both `await` and `.then(...)` in your code. They are the same, just different syntax. I suggest you to watch some videos about asynchronous code in dart to understand the concept better.